# mysql active record query not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a `varchar` column which stores the dates as `26/02/2013`. I need to convert it to date format for comparison. As a test query i use the query below in active record to fetch all records having date as `26/02/2013`

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('salesinvoices');
$this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(`date`,"%d/%m/%y")', 'CONVERT("26/02/13")');
```

This always returns no result. Whats wrong here.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, why not store dates as dates?

Comment: well it seems very confusing. How do i store them? How do i retrieve them? and how do i compare them?

Comment: Your query can't work because you're not using `CONVERT()` correctly, as can be seen [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html).

Comment: as what Strawberry suggested, save dates in format Y-m-d in database. About mysql date format -> [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

Comment: see my latest edit. this should work. You dont need to use the convert() function, it has nothing to do with dates.

Comment: use echo $this->db->last_query() after your where condition then check the query first.

Answer (score 1):

**edit**:

```
$this->db->where('DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%d/%m/%y")', '26/02/13',FALSE);
```

or

```
$this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE('.$date.',"%d/%m/%y")', '26/02/13',FALSE);
```

codeigniter automatically escapes where().

use this:

```
$this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(`date`,"%d/%m/%y")', 'CONVERT("26/02/13")',FALSE);
```

TIP: when you are having troubles with your db queries, this is very useful

```
    echo "<PRE>";
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    echo "</PRE>";
```

Comment: THIS GAVE ME: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3

SELECT *FROM (`salesinvoices`)WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`,"%d/%m/%y") = CONVERT("26/02/13")

Filename: C:\wamp\www\backbone\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: $this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE("invoiceDate","%d/%m/%y")', '26/02/13',FALSE); DOESN'T WORK

Comment: query returned by $this->db->last_query : SELECT *FROM (`salesinvoices`)WHERE STR_TO_DATE(invoiceDate,"%d/%m/%y") = '26/02/13'

Comment: add backticks(`) to your invoiceDate field and you should be good to go.